# Gmagick extension will not start in Ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, graphicsmagick, gmagick

I have been attempting to install the gmagick php extension, but keep getting the error:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/gmagick.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/gmagick.so: undefined symbol: DrawClearException in Unknown on line 0`

My local VM running Ubuntu 10.04 32bit has no problem installing this, but using the same packages on my Ubuntu 10.04 64bit remote server comes up with the error posted above. I've installed the 64bit version of Ubuntu on my local VM and the same problem comes up. Is this a bug with gmagick or am I missing something that needs to be done with a 64bit distro?

Comment: Have the same after dist upgrade from ubuntu server 12.04 LTS to 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the version of GraphicsMagick being installed via apt-get (1.3.5-6), whereas the newest version is 1.3.18. After installing the newer version from source the gmagick extension works on Ubuntu lucid 64bit.